# Can an AR object in the scene act as a plane that you can map other AR objects to?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

In Unity are you able to map one object to another AR object in the scene? I am displaying an object in my scene similar to a map and I want to be able to place spheres as markers onto the map itself. Can this be done? I would like to be able to move the map while keeping the markers in place.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an anchor!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor

Place the anchor where you would want the origin of the map to be. 
Attach the map to the anchor (at position 0,0,0).

Now you can attach spheres to that anchor and they'll show up relative to the map. You can also then independently move the map around. The spheres will stay attached to the anchor while the map moves.